# Share Oracle database connection in NodeJS for MVC architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, model-view-controller, node-oracledb

I'm quite new with the implementation of Oracle database with Node.js, currently I'm using `oracledb` library to connect my Node.js app to my Oracle database as follows

```js
connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
  user: "SYS",
  password: password,
  connectString: "localhost:1522/userdb",
  privilege: oracledb.SYSDBA
});
```

I set everything up as a monolithic app(It's a simple user review app) to start, but I want to split the code in User and Review Controller, the same for the service, model for both objects.

The only problem I have now (That I know of), is that I am not able to make each model (`User` and `Review`) to take that connection and simply send a query depending on what the controller needs. I tried to create a separate `db.js` file and set the connection there and then use

```js
class DBConnection {
  constructor() {
    this._connect();
  }
 async _connect() {
   try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
      user: "SYS",
      password: password,
      connectString:process.env.DATABASE,
      privilege: oracledb.SYSDBA
    });
   } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
   }
  
  }
}

module.exports = new DBConnection();
```

Then I would try to import it and use something like:

```js
connection= DBConnection();
connection.execute(query);
```

But it has not worked, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Observation: Please, please, please tell me that your application isn't connected as "SYS as SYSDBA". That level of privilege should **ONLY** be used for things like startup/shutdown, patch installation, or other system-level maintenance activity. **NEVER** for application usage.

Comment: Actually no that was just for initial testing I did create an admin user for the app usage, I do appreciate the concern on that haha.